# I am getting TypeError undefined for property 'false' in my unit test results

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am learning unit testing with mocha and chai. I have most tests passing but 1 test failing with TypeError: cannot read property 'false' of undefined.

I tried adding a third parameter 'input[2]' when calling adder but I still get the same error.

```
const adder = (a, b) => {
  if (!(typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number')) {
    throw Error('Oh no!');
  }
  return a + b;
}

module.exports = adder;


const expect = require('chai').expect;
const adder = require('../adder');

describe('adder', () => {
  it('should add two numbers', () => {
    const useCases = [
      {
        a: 2,
        b: 3,
        expected: 5
      },
      {
        a: 100,
        b: 1000,
        expected: 1100
      },
      {
        a: 10,
        b: -15,
        expected: -5
      }
    ];

    useCases.forEach(function (input) {
      const answer = adder(input.a, input.b);
      expect(answer).to.equal(input.expected);
    });
  });

  it('should give error if input not numbers', function () {
    const notNumbers = [
      ['a', 1,]
      ['b', 2]
      [2, false]
    ];
    notNumbers.forEach(function (input) {
      expect(function () {
        adder(input[0], input[1]);
      }).to.throw(Error);
    });
  });
});
```

Part of the expected result is passing, 'it adds two numbers'
adder
    √ should add two numbers
    1) should give error if input not numbers

1) adder
       should give error if input not numbers:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'false' of undefined
      at Context. (test\test-adder.js:34:7)

Comment: Ok, nvm I figured it out. I'm not sure how to delete a question though. I didn't have commas between the nested arrays in  const notNumbers. When I added them, all tests pass now.

Comment: You can just write an answer to your question describing how you fixed the problem. That way if other people have the same question as you in the future, it will help others as well.